# SQL: Select Customer from Table1 who purchased material in table2 and find out what else did that customer purchase in the same month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables that have a common column Material:

Table1

```
MaterialGroup | Material | MaterialDescription | Revenue | Customer  | Month

MG1           | DEF      | Desc1               | 12      | Customer A| Nov

MG2           | ABC      | Desc2               | 13      | Customer A| Nov

MG3           | XYZ      | Desc3               | 9       | Customer B| Dec

MG3           | LMN      | Desc3               | 9       | Customer B| Jan

MG4           | IJK      | Desc4               | 5       | Customer C| Jan
```

Table2

```
Vendor | VendorSubgroup| Material| Category

KM1    | DPPF          | ABC     | Cat1

KM2    | DPPL          | XYZ     | Cat2
```

There are two parts of the problem:

Part1 is fairly straight forward

I want to select all records from table1 where Material in table1 matches Material in table2

In the above scenario, I would want this result because the Material "ABC" and "XYZ" are present in table2:

```
MG2| ABC| Desc2| 13 | Customer A| Nov

MG3| XYZ| Desc3| 9  | Customer B| Dec
```

I used the following query to get the result and it worked:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TABLE1 AS T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T2
ON T1.MATERIAL = T2.MATERIAL
```

Part 2 is a bit complicated and I need help for this now:

After fetching all records from Table1 where material in table1 matches material in table2,  I need to go to that Customer in table1 who purchased material from table2 and find out what else did that customer buy (which materials did he buy) in that same Month?

So, in this example: I would want the following result-

```
MG1| DEF| Desc1| 12 | Customer A| Nov
```

because Customer A purchased Material from table2 - they also purchased some other material in the same month.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want this for all customers and for all months, or for a specific customer in a given month?

Comment: I want to fetch all records from table1 for all customers who purchased any material from table 2. Now I need to go to those customers (all such customers) and find out what else did they buy (any material that might not be in table2) during the same month during which they purchase material from table1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider duplicates. What if there are multiple rows in table1 for the same customer and month? Most solutions posted here will give incorrect results.

To prevent duplicates in the result, use EXISTS instead of JOIN:

```
WITH Part1Customers AS (
    SELECT TABLE1.Customer, TABLE1.[Month]
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM TABLE2
        WHERE TABLE1.MATERIAL = TABLE2.MATERIAL
    )
)
SELECT TABLE1.*
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Part1Customers 
    WHERE Part1Customers.Customer = TABLE1.Customer
    AND Part1Customers.[Month] = TABLE1.[Month]
)
```

Comment: i am unable to use this query as it is posted and get an ERROR: relation "part1purchases" does not exist.

Comment: Do you mean to sayWITH Part1Purchases AS (
    SELECT TABLE1.Customer, TABLE1.[Month]
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM TABLE2
        WHERE TABLE1.MATERIAL = TABLE2.MATERIAL
    )
)
SELECT TABLE1.*
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Part1Purchases 
    WHERE Part1Purchases.Customer = TABLE1.Customer
    AND Part1Purchases.[Month] = TABLE1.[Month]

Comment: I edited the answer already but he hasn't accepted it yet. Part1Customers has indeed to be changed to Part1Purchases in the 1st sentence

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM TABLE1 AS T
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT T1.Customer, T1.Month
    FROM TABLE1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T2
    ON T1.MATERIAL = T2.MATERIAL
) T1
ON T1.Customer = T.Customer AND T1.Month = T.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to join table1 *again* on CustomerID and Month, please find below the sample:

```
SELECT T3.*
FROM TABLE1 AS T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T2
ON T1.MATERIAL = T2.MATERIAL
INNER JOIN TABLE1 as T3
ON T1.Customer = T3.Customer AND T1.Month = T3.Month
```